# concat regex specific columns hive sql

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql

I have a table having columns

```
__word__|__f0__|__f1__|__f2__|__..__|__f99__|
   ..   |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ..  |  ...  |
```

columns f0-f99 have real numbers (vector embeddings of the word). I want to concatenate all these into single columns named embeddings as an array separated by ','

for example:

```
__word__|__embeddings___|
any word| [f0,f1,..f99] |
```

I am using wild cards for columns selection and it works fine for select statement

```
select word
        , `f.*`
from my_table
```

but doesn't work in concat_ws function

```
select word
        , CONCAT_WS(",", `f.*`) embeddings
from my_table
```

giving an error: Semantic analysis exception - column `f.*` cannot be resolved.

Does anyone have an idea how can I achieve this by using wild card or regex column specification?

Comment: Are you using Hive or MySQL?  In any case, you will most likely have to explicitly list out all the `f` columns.

Comment: I am using Hive

Comment: you need to spell out all columns, `concat_ws ( '~', col1, col2, col3, col4....)`...